# Send html file after it is created with NODE and Express

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm trying to create an HTML file, and then just send it (as a first step in a bigger project) as a response when the user is making a GET request. Depending on what request parameters the user gives, the HTML file should have a corresponding content into it.

First, I tried a simple example and I've used an `async` function since the response has to be made after the output file has been created.

Problem is: The file has the correct information in it (in this case is just a list of elements), but unfortunately, when I run the node app and I make a request, I get nothing in the body. I called `res.sendFile` after the `await` to make sure the file was successfully written. Am I missing something? Is my understanding about the ASYNC/AWAIT procedure wrong?

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
function writeFile(N, name) {  //function that writes the list of elements in a html file
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(FILEPATH, 'utf-8'); //filepath being the actual output file
    stream.once("open", () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            stream.write(`<li>idx=${i} and nm=${name}</li>\n`);
        }
        stream.end();
    });
}

app.get('/list/:name/number/:id', (req, res) => { //the params 
    var fun = async() => {
        try {
            await writeFile(req.params.id, req.params.name); //wait for writing into file
            res.sendFile(FILEPATH); 
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
    }
    fun();
});
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The function writeFile must return Promise.

```
function writeFile(N, name) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(FILEPATH, 'utf-8'); //filepath being the actual output file
    stream.once("close", resolve);
    stream.once("open", () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            stream.write(`<li>idx=${i} and nm=${name}</li>\n`);
        }
        stream.end();      
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I tried it, now I get something in the body, but only the first element of the list. And if I send the request multiple times, sometimes it returns no body. I checked the html file it is alright.

Comment: Had to actually use `stream.once("close",()=>resolve());` since "once" needs a callback function and now it works. Thank you